# Cant update paperclip attachment with fog gem to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I am trying to upload images to s3 but i am facing this error
"Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key"

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :attachment,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {:provider => "AWS",
                       access_key_id: 'key_id',secret_access_key: 'access_key'},
  :fog_directory => 'bucket_name'

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` options in `fog_credentials` instead of `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key`.

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :storage => :fog,
  :fog_credentials => {:provider => "AWS",
                       aws_access_key_id: 'key_id',aws_secret_access_key: 'access_key'},
  :fog_directory => 'bucket_name'
```

Refer to the list of **[fog_credentials options](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/Fog)**

Comment: in my image url i am getting my desktop path as well.. "https://com.bucket.name.s3.amazonaws.com//home/abhishek/Desktop/punchh-server/public176/Barbecue.png?1395418033

Comment: Glad to help.:)  My answer resolves your current question. You can't access the image is another question. I would suggest you to post a separate question related to that. You can take a look at `:path` and `:url` options of `has_attached_file` that will resolve your issue.